# Rails: Calling Common Method to Edit Various Model Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a simple method for initializing different counter fields for users.  However, I'm not sure how to set the value of a field referred to as a variable.

```
def self.initialize(user, field)
  counter = "#{field}".to_sym
  user.send(counter, nil)
  user.save        
end
```

I tried:

- `user.counter` instead of `user.send(counter)`, but it comes back with an undefined method error
- `user.send(counter) = nil`, but that's not the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby's accessors work using the `name=` method for an attribute called `name`.

You can probably access it this way through the model attributes interface:

```
user[counter] = nil
user.save
```

Alternatively, a more generic way that should work on any Ruby object that exposes an `attr_writer`, `attr_accessor`, or equivalent:

```
user.send("#{counter}=", nil)
user.save
```

You'd only use the `send` version when dealing with arbitrary method names, like you have here. Converting `to_sym` is not strictly necessary.

Always be careful to white-list the kinds of method calls you're accepting. You shouldn't let `counter` be an arbitrary user parameter without some validation.